# How to avoid Multiple Jbutton selections

Tags: java, jbutton

I am using Jbuttons for a game called who wants to be a zillionaire in an assignment. I am using the buttons for selecting an answer. Here is the code for some of the buttons. Code:

```
}

        });
        Answer2.setBounds(220, 105, 188, 25);
        panel.add(Answer2);

        Answer1 = new JButton("A");
        Answer1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        Answer1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        Answer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Answer1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                Answer1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
        Answer1.setBounds(20, 105, 188, 25);
        panel.add(Answer1);

        Answer4 = new JButton("D");
        Answer4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        Answer4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        Answer4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Answer4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        Answer4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }
});
```

At the moment multiple buttons can be selected and I wish to prevent this. It would be helpful if you could show me an example of code that could be used to do this.

Comment: do you want the other buttons to be inactive when one button is clicked?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625569/how-to-make-a-button-unclickable

Comment: No I'm using eclipse sorry I forgot to mention that in the question.

Comment: use JRadioButtons in a ButtonGroup

Comment: When a button is clicked  it will change colour but I do not want the user to be able to click more than one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the setEnable() method to make unwanted buttons disable or make a Boolean class level variable and make it true when the desired button is clicked. Then before invoking other buttons' algorithms simply check whether this variable's value is true.

**Edited**

```
   public class YourClassName{

       static boolean isAnswerSelected = false;

       //your codes goes here

       Answer1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT); 
       Answer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

             if(!isAnswerSelected){  //this line will check whether an answer is already selected
                  isAnswerSelected = true;   // this will make other answers unselectable
                  Answer1.setBackground(Color.BLUE); 
                  Answer1.setForeground(Color.WHITE); 
             }
         } 
       });

   }
```

Use the above if statement and isAnswerSelected = true; line for all your actionPerformed() methods for all buttons.

Comment: Hi, was just wondering is you could give an example thanks. If so that would be great thanks

Comment: private JButton Answer1;
 private JButton Answer2;

Comment: Answer1 = new JButton("A");
  Answer1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
  Answer1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
  Answer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Answer1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    Answer1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
   }
  });
  Answer1.setBounds(20, 105, 188, 25);
  panel.add(Answer1);

Comment: Answer2 = new JButton("B");
  Answer2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
  Answer2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
  Answer2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Answer2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    Answer2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    
   }
  
  });
  Answer2.setBounds(220, 105, 188, 25);
  panel.add(Answer2);

Comment: If possible could you give an example with the code I have added in comments by showing how I could use the SetEnable method.

Comment: @jehangir Please check the edited section. You can use this type of format to make other questions un selectable if one is selected.